# Azure DevOps agents: MS hosted or Self hosted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have

**1 Microsoft hosted agent**
[image]

**1 Self hosted agent**
[image]

How to I instruct my yml pipleline to run on **EITHER** of them?
If the one is busy use the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. There is a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-agent-pools-to-contain-microsoft-hosted-and/396893) for this. But for the moment you can use one or another.